# Why does the http error when I try to install bWAPP?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm try to install bWAPP on apache. Then I click 'here' in install page I watch http error 500. Below is the error log.

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::86c4:29f1:7339:637b%wlp2s0. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Apr 18 02:36:31.198342 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1705:tid 140388347382720] 
AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 18 02:36:31.198495 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1705:tid 140388347382720] 
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Apr 18 02:47:37.690143 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1705:tid 140388347382720] 
AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

I set ServerName localhost. It don't help. I don't now where the problem is

Comment: Kindly be specific while asking your question. State all the steps prior to clicking 'here' it will help people in providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Apache config file, perhaps in /etc/apache2/httpd, you need to set ServerName. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

You can set the server name to almost anything, example.com or mytestserver.com.

If you need to visit your sites from another computer you can either enter its IP address as the URL or example.com or mytestserver.com but you need to modify your hosts file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Example hosts file;

```
192.168.0.10      example.com
```

Localhost is probably not a good idea as that has special meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

I hope this helps you.